# Imprimir memória disponível em C

Tags: c, linux, windows, memória, malloc

Como saber a quantidade de memoria disponível antes de fazer o `malloc()`?

Gostava de imprimir o valor da memoria que ainda está disponível para poder ser alocada, o código tem de correr em Windows e Linux.

Num computador penso que não seja muito importante esse tipo de informações, mas num microcontrolador saber a memoria que ainda está disponível deve de ser bastante útil para futuras ações.

Algo como `GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memInfo);`, pelas pesquisas que fiz não achei um método que realmente funcionasse.

Comment: Quem votar negativamente poderia comentar para saber o que melhorar na pergunta, penso que seja uma pergunta bastante pertinente e que não existe no StackOverflowPT !

Comment: não existe uma maneira padronizada de obter esta informação, pelo que andei vendo no SO em inglês o que existem são hacks aproximados...provavelmente num microcontrolador também deve haver alguma maneira específica de obter esta informação...obs. não dei negativo

Comment: Eu tambem andei a ver por lá, não queria uma maneira padronizada, apenas algo que funcionasse.

Answer (score 1):

Em um microcontrolador tem que ver a API dele e ele não rodará Linux, muito menos Windows. Mas em microcontroladores é como não se usar `malloc()`, pelo menos em cenários de tempo real ou de altíssima restrição, inclusive pode nem ter uma API. Programar para microcontroladores é diferente de programar para microcomputadores, por isso que eu falo que as pessoas tendem a querer fazer código que rode no Windows e no microcontrolador e quase sempre isso não faz sentido. Até a biblioteca padrão do C costuma ter uma implementação muito diferente e limitada.

Memória no nível micro é algo complicado, e não é fácil pregar com precisão, depende da estratégia de alocação da aplicação, da biblioteca usada, arquitetura, e outros fatores. Pode dar um `malloc()` e mudar nada, porque efetivamente não ocorrerá um alocação, usará algo já alocado anteriormente no sistema operacional. Ocorrerá uma alocação interna. Isto pode ocorrer por uma questão de mapeamento ou porque o `free()` nem sempre libera para o sistema operacional.

No Windows já sabe a função correta, no Linux é a [`Sysconf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sysconf.html).

Comment: Eu não sei usar a função que referi, vi essa função num site sem explicar como ela funcionava, eu pesquisei um pouco porem nao sei como usar. Não sei se estou imprimindo um valor aleatorio ou estou imprimindo mesmo o espaço de memoria disponivel, pois não tenho a certeza.

Comment: Sua pergunta não fala nisto e aí ela se torna ampla, respondi porque ela parecia conceitual, se não era o que queria saber, no mínimo ela não está clara. Isto pode ocorrer porque você tem uma tendência a colocar um monte de informação irrelevante para a pergunta e aí gasta pouco com a real dúvida, faz as pessoas entenderam outra coisa. Como isto é frequente, vou preferir fechar suas perguntas como não clara até que fique claro o que quer saber de fato e não o que está escrito. Escreve na pergunta o que quer saber, não escreva outras coisas.

Comment: Mas eu coloquei a pergunta central no inicio do texto, bastava apenas essa pergunta para as pessoas responderem, depois separei isso por um `linha` e fiz um resumo do que esperava. É uma pergunta ampla? No texto que escrevi apenas tem UMA pergunta, que é a duvida que quero saber.

Comment: Falei do microcontrolador para dizer que seria pertinente imprimirmos esse valor, isso claramente que nao era uma pergunta, nem era a pergunta central. Aliás, eu coloquei a negrito que era em Windows e Linux. Se um microcontrolador nao roda linux nem windows entao não tem como responder de acordo com isso. O microcontrolador podia ser falado no fim da resposta de alguem, era opção.

Comment: E como vamos adivinhar que ela é a central se a maior parte do texto é sobre outra coisa? E se for, ela continua não clara ou ampla. No bloco amarelo aí do lado tem uma pergunta chamada "O que fazer com perguntas no estilo “Como fazer X?”" Leia-a. Daí a pergunta fica ampla, sem contexto, sem um código, sem um dúvida específica fica complicado dar uma resposta que seja correta, seria chute, conforme eu já falei antes. Eu até respondi porque ela parecia mais conceitual, ela parecia ser sobre um *overview*, respondi "por cima". O Victor tem um comentário muito bom que não vou achar que fala algo:

Comment: Se você pergunta sobre como construir uma casa, o máximo que terá de resposta é que precisa levantar paredes com tijolos e fazer um acabamento. Se perguntar porque a parede que você fez "desse jeito" está torta e como resolver, ou porque a massa de assentar está mole, como fixa bem o tijolo na parede, aí terá uma resposta mais específica. Ah, eu eu respondi para Linux e Windows, de forma geral, como a pergunta foi feita. Quando você tentar entender o site e parar de lutar contra ele você se dará melhor.

Comment: Fui pesquisar mais um pouco e ironicamente encontrei no [StackOverflowEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513505/how-to-get-available-memory-c-g/26639774) a minha pergunta, a pergunta central era exatamente igual à minha e a resposta do @Travis Gockel era exatamente o que eu queria, bem como outras respostas. Eu não estou tentando lutar, apenas gostava de saber uma função com o objetivo que pretendia para mais tarde implementar. Provavelmente deveria de ter procurado mais em vez de ter perguntado logo, mas assim poderia ajudar outros, como aconteceu no StackOverflowEN

Comment: Aqui não é o SOen, e a pergunta está muito longe de ser a mesma, é sobre o mesmo assunto, lá está muito mais objetiva e mesmo ela provocou uma resposta que se eu postasse aqui você reclamaria que não tem nada com o que você perguntou, e de fato a pergunta lá é muito ruim e deveria ser fechada. Não justifica errar aqui tb. Tudo você transforma em um fórum de discussão. Já está bom, não posso ficar explicando tudo para você o tempo todo, não é adequado, as perguntas precisam ser boas pro si só,se precisar debater todas as perguntas que fizer fica muito improdutivo e você monopoliza muita energia

Comment: Você mudar a pergunta depois dela feita não pode, assim invalida o que eu respondi. Vou repetir mais uma vez. Aqui não é um fórum. Você faz um pergunta e espera uma resposta. Pode usar os comentários para algum esclarecimento rápido, mas se precisar debater o assunto, se precisar mudar a pergunta depois de respondida a pergunta tem problemas e por isto está fechada. Mesmo editada não dá para saber o que quer sem ver os comentários postados depois. E ainda é ampla só pedindo o código.

Comment: Na altura que editei era para ver se dava para voltar a reabrir, mas já percebi que a pergunta está ampla. Obrigado na mesma